# jQuery.getJSON always returns empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, undefined, getjson

I've been looking for a way to include an object from a JSON file, and I've found several pages summarizing how to use $.getJSON(), and even a few answers here, but none have worked. Some have suggested I do it this way:

```
var json;

$.getJSON("dir/1.json", function(response){
    json = response;
});
```

And some have suggested it this way:

```
var json = $.getJSON("dir/1.json");
```

Neither of these work. When I try to call a property of `json`, such as `json.title`, it just gives me an error saying the variable is undefined. No one else seems to be having this problem, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a relative path and an absolute path?

Comment: Yes, and the file is relative to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
var json = $.getJSON( "dir/1.json" )
    .done(function( response ) {
        json = response;
        console.log( "json variable ready" );
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log( "error" );
    });
```

**Update**

The response object returned by $.getJSON() implements the promise interface, giving it all the properties, methods, and behavior of a promise. So json isn't ready until a response is returned or the done function is fired.

Comment: The response object returned by $.getJSON() implements the `promise` interface, giving it all the properties, methods, and behavior of a `promise`. So `json` isn't ready until a response is returned or the `done` function is fired.

Comment: Just did it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The response is deferred. At the time you're reading the variable, the response likely hasn't responded yet. Try accessing the variable inside the function callback, right after `json = response;`